# C++ - Using Hunspell with MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, hunspell

[After I managed to get Hunspell working with a Win32 console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703520/c-using-hunspell-1-3-2-with-visual-studio-2010), I want to use Hunspell in an MFC application in the same solution.
I get the following error when I try to compile the MFC application.

```
spellcheck\hunspell-src\hunspell\replist.hxx(23): error C2062: type 'const char' unexpected
spellcheck\hunspell-src\hunspell\replist.hxx(23): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

Some information about the solution:

- The solution is called spellcheck.
- The Hunspell source files are located in `spellcheck\hunspell-src\hunspell` and `spellcheck\hunspell-src\win_api`.
- The project `libhunspell` has been imported and compiles without errors.
- A console application in the solution uses the same hunspell dll/source files and has **no errors**.
- The console application has been setup accordingly to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703520/c-using-hunspell-1-3-2-with-visual-studio-2010)
- The folders `HunSpell-Src` and `HunSpell-Dic` are NOT located in a project folder but in the solution folder `spellcheck` and referenced properly.

I have setup the MFC application as following:

1. Added a new MFC application (SDI) as project to the solution called `MFC2`.
2. Added a reference to the project `libhunspell` to `MFC2`.
3. `Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > C++ > General > Additional Include Directories` has been set to: `..\hunspell-src\hunspell;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)` (the same as the console application)
4. `Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories` has been set to: `..\hunspell-src\win_api\Debug_dll\libhunspell;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)` (the same as the console application)
5. Added `#include "../HunSpell-Src/win_api/hunspelldll.h"`under `#include MainFrm.h` in `Mainfrm.cpp`.

I decided to put the #include of `hunspelldd.h` in `Mainfrm.cpp` and omit setting up a dialog and calling it in order to keep this question as short as possible. Nevertheless I have setup a project as described that produces said error messages.

Because the console application compiles fine, I assume something MFC specific is causing the problem.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add "#undef near" before class declaration in replist.hxx

Comment: Now it compiles, although with a couple of warnings. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me as well.  @Igor: care to give any explanation about why that is necessary?

Comment: There is "#define near" in WinAPI minwindef.h which is visible in that scope. By this reason preprocessor generates error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look for an error in the include file just before replist.hxx, perhaps a missing ending semicolon on a class definition.

Comment: I checked for that and couldn't find any. If a simple syntax error like that were responsible, would libhunspell even be able to compile (which it did)?